# Is the sequence of opcodes (BINARY_SUBSCR, GET_ITER) somehow optimized in CPython?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, optimization, cpython, opcode

I'm doing some benchmarking with Python3.5, and, while comparing the following code samples, I noticed `f1` runs more than 45% faster than `f2`:

```
def f1():
    acc = 0
    a = a_
    for i in a[100:900]:
        acc += i

    return acc

def f2():
    acc = 0
    a = a_
    for i in range(100, 900):
        acc += a[i]

return acc
```

It is somewhat counterintuitive to me, since `for i in a[100:900]` looks like performing an unneeded copy of the data. This confirmed when disassembling the code by the presence of the [BINARY_SUBSCR](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBSCR) opcode. Here is the relevant part of the bytecode:

```
  9          12 SETUP_LOOP              34 (to 49)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             21 LOAD_CONST               3 (900)
             24 BUILD_SLICE              2
             27 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 GET_ITER
        >>   29 FOR_ITER                16 (to 48)
             32 STORE_FAST               2 (i)
```

How would you explain the good performances of `f1`? Is the sequence  [BINARY_SUBSCR](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBSCR), [GET_ITER](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-GET_ITER) somehow optimized to avoid data copying?

---

For reference here is bellow the full test code. I tried to increase the list size up to 1_000_000 items, and `f1` still performs better. Same thing when using `array.array`.

```
a_ = list(range(1000))

def f1():
    acc = 0
    a = a_
    for i in a[100:900]:
        acc += i

    return acc

def f2():
    acc = 0
    a = a_
    for i in range(100, 900):
        acc += a[i]

    return acc

from dis import dis
from timeit import timeit

for f in f1,f2:
    dis(f)
    print(timeit(f, number=200000))
    print()
```

Result:

```
  6           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (acc)

  7           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (a)

  8          12 SETUP_LOOP              34 (to 49)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             21 LOAD_CONST               3 (900)
             24 BUILD_SLICE              2
             27 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 GET_ITER
        >>   29 FOR_ITER                16 (to 48)
             32 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

  9          35 LOAD_FAST                0 (acc)
             38 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             41 INPLACE_ADD
             42 STORE_FAST               0 (acc)
             45 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           29
        >>   48 POP_BLOCK

 11     >>   49 LOAD_FAST                0 (acc)
             52 RETURN_VALUE
5.18372956989333

 14           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (acc)

 15           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (a)

 16          12 SETUP_LOOP              37 (to 52)
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             21 LOAD_CONST               3 (900)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             27 GET_ITER
        >>   28 FOR_ITER                20 (to 51)
             31 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

 17          34 LOAD_FAST                0 (acc)
             37 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             40 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             43 BINARY_SUBSCR
             44 INPLACE_ADD
             45 STORE_FAST               0 (acc)
             48 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           28
        >>   51 POP_BLOCK

 19     >>   52 LOAD_FAST                0 (acc)
             55 RETURN_VALUE
8.191981540992856
```

Comment: You haven't defined the global `a_`, then you assign it to a inside each function: `a = a_` (instead of passing it as a function argument). Presumably `a_` is some global list of int. Can you edit a definition of `a_` into your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special optimization to avoid data copying (it wouldn't be safe to do so; modifying the source sequence after the slice isn't allowed to change the contents of the slice after all). Indexed access is just *slow* (loading the sequence, the index, executing a `BINARY_SUBSCR` over and over, which has to unpack the index each time), and making shallow copies of a `list` is (comparatively) fast (it's effectively just a `memcpy`-like operation along with a bunch of reference count increments).

The loop over a `range` also involves actually making the index wrappers each time; once you're outside the small `int` cache bounds, it has to actually allocate a `int` each time and fill it in. By contrast, once the slice is constructed, direct iteration of the slice is just incrementing a reference count and returning the existing object, no memory overhead.

So your comparison isn't "copying a big chunk of a `list`" to "accessing each element one by one", it's "copying a big chunk of a `list` as a single operation" to "doing lots of work to construct `int`s, then unpack them, over and over, to extract a big chunk of a `list` element by element, with bytecode interpreter overhead on *every* extraction".

Point is, there's a reason `for i in range(len(seq)): ... do stuff with seq[i] ...` is considered an anti-pattern, and it's not just because it's uglier; it's a lot slower too.